# Full Text Search Using Multiple Partial Words

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search, wildcard

I have a sql server database that has medical descriptions in it.  I've created a full text index on it, but I'm still figuring out how this works.

The easiest example to give is if there is a description of `Hypertensive heart disease`

Now they would like to be able to type `hyp hea` as a search term and have it return that.

So from what I've read it seems like my query needs to be something like

```
DECLARE @Term VARCHAR(100)
SET @Term = 'NEAR(''Hyper*'',''hea*'')'
SELECT * FROM Icd10Codes WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @Term)
```

If I take the wild card out for Hypertensive and heart, and type out the full words it works, but adding the wild card in returns nothing.

If it makes any difference I'm using Sql Server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was a weird syntax issue that didn't cause an error, but stopped the search from working.

I changed it to

`SELECT * FROM Icd10Codes where CONTAINS(description, '"hyper*" NEAR "hea*"')`

The key here being I needed double quotes `"` and not to single quotes.  I assumed it was two single quotes, the first to escape the second, but it was actually double quotes.  The above query returns the results exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM Icd10Codes where SOUNDEX(description)=soundex('Hyp');

SELECT * FROM Icd10Codes where DIFFERENCE(description,'hyp hea')>=2;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it returned a row with this value:  `Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers`.  The letters hea aren't anywhere in that.

Comment: I need it to return rows with both words next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a like statement. You can find a thorough explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Icd10Codes WHERE Icd10Codes LIKE '%hyp hea%';
```

And then instead of putting the String in there just use a variable.

If you need to search for separated partial words, as in an array of search terms, it gets a bit tricky, since you need to dynamically build the SQL statement.

MSSQL provides a few features for full text search. You can find those [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc879300(v=sql.105)). One of them is the `CONTAINS` keyword:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE CONTAINS (column , 'string1 string2 string3');
```

Comment: I can't use your first suggestion because that would match the results I need.  Those are two partial words with the ending missing.  Your second one gives me an error.
`SELECT * FROM Icd10Codes where CONTAINS(description, 'hyp hea')`
`Syntax error near ''hea'' in the full-text search condition ''hyp' 'hea''. (Line 1)`

Answer (score 0):

For me - this had more mileage.
create a calculated row with fields as full text search.
fullname / company / lastname all searchable.

```sql
    ALTER TABLE profiles ADD COLUMN fts tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(profiles.company, '') || ' ' || coalesce(profiles.broker, '') || ' ' || coalesce(profiles.firstname, '') ||  ' ' || coalesce(profiles.lastname, '') || ' ' )) stored;



      let { data, error } = await supabase.from('profiles')
      .select()
      .textSearch('fts',str)
```